# Changing var res to be max value of a given array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, function, scope

So this is a simple one, I only need to find the max value in a given array. The only axiom is that all of the items in the array will be numbers. My issue is that the res variable does not change. I tried the same in Python and it works with no issues but in JavaScript it seems that the value does not change or more-so it changes only for the if and then it goes back to its original value.

So I have tried fiddling with the var keyword, I have tried placing the var in different positions of the code (out of the for loop, in the for loop, in the if statement) I tried to do it without the var keyword as well but it still does not work

```
     function max(arr){    
        var res = 0;
    for (i=1; i>arr.length; i++){

        if (arr[i-1]>arr[i]){
          res = arr[i-1]
        }

        else if (arr[i-1]<arr[i]){
           res = arr[i]
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (res<arr[i]){
            res = arr[i]
        }
    }
    console.log(res)
}
```

This is the Python code that works

```
def Max(arr):
  res = 0
  for i in range(1,len(arr)):
    if arr[i-1]>arr[i]:
      res = arr[i-1]
    elif arr[i-1]<arr[i]:
      res = arr[i]
  for i in range(len(arr)):
    if res<arr[i]:
      res = arr[i]

  print(res)
```

If we take that the arr will be [1,2,3,7,5,6] the result should be 7 (What I get in Python) but in JavaScript I get 0 or whatever I have set res to be (e.g. if res was set to 10 then it will console.log 10 as well)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop never works with this condition:

```
i > arr.length
```

because i starts with `1` and this is only `true` with an empty array.

A better approach with a single loop and a single check.

```js
function max(array) {
    var max = array[0],
        i;
        
    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
    }
    
    return max;
}

console.log(max([1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6]))
```

Comment: Nice solution did not think to do it this way. Well that is what I get for starting to program since I woke up :D Also yeah I just did not notice it, but would have if I had gotten to that loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors, I've commented on them. First you need to write `let` or `var` in front of `i` in loops, if you don't do it  `i` becomes a global variable. You can read about block scoping variables. Your second loop made no sense, as you need to check if the `i` is less than `arr.length`;

```js
function max(arr){    
    var res = 0;
    for (let i=1; i>arr.length; i++){ // let i

        if (arr[i-1]>arr[i]){
          res = arr[i-1]
        }

        else if (arr[i-1]<arr[i]){
           res = arr[i]
        }
    }
    // without let, 'i' would be a global variable equal to arr.length-1 here and your second loop wouldn't execute.
    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){ // let i; i< arr.length; 
        if (res<arr[i]){
            res = arr[i]
        }
    }
    console.log(res)
}

max([2,3,4,5,10,1])
```

**EDIT:**

And here is a really easy way to find the biggest number in an array:

```js
let maxNumber = Math.max(...[1,2,3,4,5,10,255,1]);
console.log(maxNumber);
```

Comment: Damn I did not notice that i>arr.length. Thanks for pointing it out :). So it seems an issue with i and it's scope. Interesting. Thank you for the fast response <3

Comment: @BashtaTi, nice nickname, you can check my edit, if this is going to easier for you to use.

Comment: Thanks :D, Yeah it will be a faster solution but I gotta do this only with the pure basics since I am still learning.